# Commutator Identity and Commutator Subgroup

Tags: group-theory

It is well known that if $G$ is any group in which $[G,G]$ is abelian, then for any $a,b,c\in G$,

$$\bigl[[a,b],c\bigr]\cdot\bigl[[b,c],a\bigr]\cdot\bigl[[c,a],b\bigr]=1$$

Conversely, if this identity holds for all $a,b,c\in G$ then is it necessary that $[G,G]$ is abelian?

Comment: There are no counterexamples of order at most $200$.

Comment: @Derek: Great! Thanks for the important information.

Answer (score 4):

[B. H. Neumann proved](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/glasgow-mathematical-journal/article/div-classtitleon-a-conjecture-of-hanna-neumanndiv/A68EBF2050CF758A68ACB6A3447B0DD9) that there is a $4$-generator, non-metabelian group, all of whose $3$-generated subgroups are metabelian. So in this group the identity
$$\bigl[[a,b],c\bigr]\cdot\bigl[[b,c],a\bigr]\cdot\bigl[[c,a],b\bigr]=1$$
holds.

Neumann' s example is a finite $2$-group. Compare with [Theorem 4 of this paper by Alperin](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-01/S0002-9947-1963-0142640-5/S0002-9947-1963-0142640-5.pdf).